# SUMIFS function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need help in figuring out on the project I've been working on lately.  In excel, I know how to use `SUMIFS`. I know it's possible to make it work in VBA (VBA beginner here) but I really have no idea how. As I would like to use the formula instead(manually) or just reference the columns, I really need to do it in VBA, because the sheet gets updated every month. This is the formula:

```
=SUMIFS(N:N,A:A,"*Team*", A:A, "*Total*")
```

I have a sheet (Budget) that gets updated every month. It should find the words `"Team"` and `"Total"` in column A til the last row and sum up those Amount in column N (same row), and find the words "Grand Total" til the last row in column A and its sum will be placed on column N. Here's the sample table.

[image]

This problem has been bugging me lately and I really need help. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: i strongly recommend against using a A:A range in the sumifs formula. Sumifs is a array formula, and will very quickly become very slow, if you reference the entire column. try to go for A1:A50000 , or however many rows you need.

Comment: I'll take note of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just assign the formula string to the `Formula` property of a `Range` object, so that shouldn't be any more difficult than entering it into the formula bar, really. You can keep it pretty much as is.

It sounds like the only issue you really have is locating `"Grand Total"`.

If it's always the last row in column A, you can do the following:

```
Dim intLastRow As Long
intLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Now that you have your last row, you can address your cell in column N and assign it your formula:

```
Cells(intLastRow, "N").Formula = "=SUMIFS(N:N,A:A,""*Team*"",A:A,""*Total*"")"
```

The only tricky thing here is that any quotes (used in string literals) must be doubled.